# Converting list of strings to integers PYTHON

Tags: python, string, list, csv, integer

```
import csv

with open('Football_data.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

dates = []
homeTeam = []
awayTeam = []
fullTimeHomeGoals = []
fullTimeAwayGoals = []
fullTimeResult = []


for row in readCSV:
    #ignore row[0]
    date = row[1]
    home = row[2]
    away = row[3]
    FTHG = row[4]
    FTAG = row[5]
    FTR = row[6]

    dates.append(date)
    homeTeam.append(home)
    awayTeam.append(away)
    fullTimeHomeGoals.append(FTHG)
    fullTimeAwayGoals.append(FTAG)
    fullTimeResult.append(FTR)



    print(date, home,FTHG, FTAG, away)
```

I am trying to convert the data from my CSV file to an integer.

I have tried

```
FTHG = int(row[4])
FTAG = int(row[5])
```

But get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/*****/PycharmProjects/untitled/first.py", line 19, in 
<module>
FTHG = int(row[4])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FTHG'
```

In order to do some analysis of the football data in the CSV file the 
values representing goals scored need to be stored as integers.
As all data in a CSV file is string data I need to convert.
The syntax I have used does work outside my loop.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to convert the header row. Use `next(readCSV)` before the loop to skip the first row.

Comment: of course! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
import csv

with open('Football_data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    ################ This is the header of each columns
    next(readCSV) ## This line reads it so it is not read
    ################ when iterating in the for loop

# ... #
```

Comment: Excuse me... I have 3 lines of comment, isn't that enough. Anyway, If you need more tell me.